# How to change the order of list elements?

Tags: r, list

Hello I created a function which reorders nested elements of a list that way:

```
library(magrittr)
fun=function(string,NO){
  lapply(strsplit(string,","),function(x) 
    paste(c(by(x, c(s<-rep(1:NO,2),rep(0,length(x)-length(s)))
               ,paste0,collapse=",")),collapse=", "))
}
LIST<-list(list("DC,MD,MA,Baltimore,Washington,Boston,France,China"), list("DC,MD,MA,Baltimore,Washington,Boston,France,China,Turkey"))
rapply(LIST,fun,how="list",NO=3)
```

How can I modify it to put the city before state?

Comment: it's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. Are you trying to pull apart a string and put together the pieces in an arbitrary order?

Comment: Im giving as input the string the list element and NO is the number of the pairs (city,state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd refactor entirely. If you want to rearrange a string with N states followed by N cities, and then put them back in order with city, state, first get pull the string apart entirely.

```
state_city <- unlist(strsplit(string, ", "))
state <- state_city[1:(length(state_city)/2)]
city <- state_city[(length(state_city)/2 + 1):length(state_city)]
paste(city, state, sep = ", ", collapse = ", ")
```

as a function:

```
f <- function(string, NO){
    state_city <- unlist(strsplit(string, ", "))
    state <- state_city[1:(length(state_city)/2)]
    city <- state_city[(length(state_city)/2 + 1):length(state_city)]
    paste(city, state, sep = ", ", collapse = ", ")
}
```

You don't actually need `NO`, but i put it in there in case you want to do something else with it.

Comment: Is it posible to just change the order of the words after creating the list with my inital way?

Comment: It's possible, but i really wouldn't recommend it. It's hard to read and full of things that don't actually get the code closer to your output. For one, you're calling lapply on a list of length 1.

Comment: f(output[3],2)
Error in strsplit(string, ", ") : non-character argument
Called from: strsplit(string, ", ") I take this error

Comment: this is output[3] [[1]]
[1] "MA, TN, Boston, Nashville"

Comment: output[3] is not a string, then. It's a nested list element. You'll need to extract the string from your output, or post a [reprex](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex.html) if you need more troubleshooting.

Comment: The guess, based on what you posted, would be that you should extract the output with double brackets: `output[[3]]` but i don't know for sure what you're working with without a reprex.